# How to hide banner ad when navigating to next page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

I am setting ads in flutter app using [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) plugin. I tried banner ad and it is working fine but, when i navigate to another page it still remains at its position. I want that ad should hide when navigating to another page.

The code snippet is as follows.

```
BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
  adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
myBanner
  // typically this happens well before the ad is shown
  ..load()
  ..show(
    // Positions the banner ad 60 pixels from the bottom of the screen
    anchorOffset: 60.0,
    // Banner Position
    anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
  );
```

Comment: Using [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) to detect the route you want to show bannerAd is at the top or not,And now only way to hide banner is call myBanner.dispose().

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RouteObserver`:

```
class AdmobObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {

  BannerAd _myBanner = BannerAd(
    adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
    size: AdSize.smartBanner,
    listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
      print("BannerAd event is $event");
    },
  );

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);

    if (route.settings.name == '/') {
      // show the banner when navigating to home screen
      _showBannerAd();
    } else {
      // hide the banner when navigating to another screen
      _myBanner.dispose();
    }

  }


  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (previousRoute.settings.name == '/') {
      // show the banner again when returning back to the home screen
      _showBannerAd();
    }
  }

  void _showBannerAd() {
    _myBanner
      ..load()
      ..show(
        anchorOffset: 60.0,
        // Banner Position
        anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }
}
```

Then you need to add this observer to your `MaterialApp`:

```
  static AdmobObserver admobObserver = AdmobObserver();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[admobObserver],
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Working just one time (one navigation), after that i got this error everytime it lock my navigator, any idea? 

`Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2416 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.`

Comment: Having the exact issue of _debugLocked. @Naografix, did you find a solution?

Comment: This gives me new erros like 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4506 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Answer (score 1):

`dispose()` will be called when a page is destroyed. So you can distroy banner ad there.

```
  @override
  void dispose() {

    myBanner.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide when show new Screen and re show when user return to last screen, you need to **dispose** before start new page and use **async** and **await** to await until new page pop from navigator, lets show some code

```
 BannerAd bannerAd;

    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initAds();
  }   


   void openNewPage() async{
     //hide banner before start new page
     bannerAd?.dispose();
     await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MySecondScreen()));
     //now user is return to this page so reshow banner
     initAds();
    }


    @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    bannerAd?.dispose();
    interstitialAd?.dispose();
  }



  void initAds() async {

      bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: kReleaseMode ? Constant.BANNER_AD_ID : BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          print("BannerAd event is $event");
        },
      );

      bannerAd
        // typically this happens well before the ad is shown
        ..load()
        ..show(
          anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
        );
    

  
  }
```

so inside this method we hide/reshow banner

```
void openNewPage() async{
         //hide banner before start new page
         bannerAd?.dispose();
         await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MySecondScreen()));
         //now user is return to this page so reshow banner
         initAds();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

call `Navigator.pop();`

before calling `Navigator.push()` . This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.
Consider two pages/screens as HomePage and SecondPage.

Step 1. Add this code in HomePage to go to SecondPage

```
myBanner?.dispose();
myBanner = null;
Navigator.push(context,
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
```

this will remove BannerAd object and banner will be disappeared.

Step 2. Add this code in SecondPage

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if(secondPageBanner == null){
        initState();
      }
    });
```

Put your BannerAd initialization/ Declaration code into initState() function.
This will show Banner in SecondPage.

Step 3. Add this code in SecondPage when back to Homepage

```
secondPageBanner?.dispose();
     if(secondPageBanner != null){
         secondPageBanner = null;
       }

      setState(() {
         Navigator.pop(context);
       });
```

This will make secondPageBanner hidden.

Step 4. Add this code in Homepage

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          if(myBanner == null){
            initState();
          }
        });
```

OR like this

```
void function(){
    if(myBanner == null){
         initState();
      }
}
```

in a button click function that button is normally clicked by user.

This will show myBanner Ad again in HomePage.

Comment: Do not forget to cancel timer.