# Flutter firebase_admob banner is still shown on every screen

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

I'm using firebase_admob package in a flutter project, and when I load and show a banner ad on the first screen it's loaded and displayed correctly, but when I navigate to a new screen that doesn't contain a banner, the old banner is still shown on the new screen,

this is the creation code of the banner called in the initState()

```
BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
        adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
        //Change BannerAd adUnitId with Admob ID
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        targetingInfo: AdsUtil.targetingInfo,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            // dispose after you received the loaded event seems okay.
            if (mounted) {
              _bannerAd..show();
              setState(() {
                isBannerShown = true;
              });
            } else {
              _bannerAd = null;
              setState(() {
                isBannerShown = false;
              });
            }
          } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            _bannerAd = null;
            setState(() {
              isBannerShown = false;
            });
          }
          //  print("********** ********** BannerAd $event");
        });
  }
@override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Navigation to the second screen code :

```
    IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SettingsPage.routeName);
                    },
                  ),
```

I want to find a solution that when I navigate to a new screen the old banner get destroyed and not displayed in the new screen I navigated to.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code where it is showing the ad?

Comment: 1. Did you push hot reload during/before the page transition? 2. Is it happening during debugging or with the release app also? I am suspecting it's happening as the adview is rendered as native view and it's not getting disposed due to some reason.

Comment: @Adnankarim : i'm showing the add in the createBannerAd() method shown in the question :   _bannerAd..show();

Comment: @SanjaySharma it's not getting disposed even in the release app, I can dispose the banner on WillPopScope but when I'll return the first screen , it will not be able to show the banner.

Comment: Can you share the code of navigation between screens?

Comment: @SanjaySharma : ok I've added it to the question.

Comment: check the answer. Please mark and upvote if you find it helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push a new page then `dispose` method is not called the native adView remains on the next screen as an overlay widget because it's not part of the widget tree. You need to keep track of pages and then load the banner and dispose it as per page change and reload the ad when the page reloads.
**So instead of pushing the page, replacing it with the new page will fix the issue**.
You can create `RouteObserver` and keep track of the page change. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645084/4788260) answer.